# Google App Script DoGet method not returning Auth error on multiple google account logged in

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, google-apps

I have a webapp which calls googleAppScript `doGet` method, it used to return an auth error if user had multiple google account signed in at the same time, which i was handling accordingly in my app, but now it is returning just an empty string on error.

Comment: The problem that you are having is important, and of interest to many Apps Script users.  Obviously you'd like a solution to the problem, but your post is probably considered "off-topic" to StackOverflow.  What Apps Script returns for an error message is controlled by engineers at Google.  If you want to get the attention of someone at Google, it's better to make a post at the [Google Apps Script Community](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-apps-script-community)  and search the [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/69270374)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i figured out the issue. The problem was due to Chrome 73 update, which was not allowing the http calls to Google App Script from chrome extension and was returning just an empty string as response.
I resolved this issue by moving my calls from content scripts to extension's background.js.